# What mitigation is taken while filming 'raining' scenes

Tags: film-techniques

I understand that most rain scenes are artificially produced. But both filming in a studio and outdoors, there is an incredible amount of valuable electronics.

**How is filming equipment kept 'dry'**, when there is artificial rain, fog, and even real rain all around; as in, keeping the equipment dry?

[image: Scene shot in heavy rain]

Comment: I take it that still is from X-Files?

Comment: Anecdote: many scenes  in *Jurassic Park* were shot during a real hurricane (the hurricane Iniki in Hawaii). During the other shots during that hurricane, short-circuits made the T-rex animatronics to move. Scary!

Comment: Too short for an answer as bird man (coo) already has the bulk of it, but most equipment is not damaged by fog, maybe only lenses. and even then. For rain, artificial or not, simply covering the thing with plastic, and using proper water-resistant connectors is enough. Ever been to a rain or shine concert? Lights and sound and video equipment is hearty. It's only super strength rain with wind, flooding thats dangerous.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Rain jackets for cameras are available in market. If the rain is artificially created, we just have to focus on the frame we are shooting. We don't need water all over the place, but just within the frame. And if there is a lighting setup that's placed within that boundary, we have to some how keep the HMIs, sound gears, etc dry. Well, we could use umbrellas or rain coats for that. Also, we must focus on the safety of people. We can use GFCIs for protection from electric shocks as we need to power some device in the rain. A ground fault circuit interrupter (GFCI) or Residual Current Device (RCD) is a device that shuts off an electric power circuit when it detects that current is flowing along an unintended path, such as through water or a person.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I was particularly concerned about the equipment, but also the threat  to electrocution, so +1 for addressing each.

Comment: @Mikey You might get more answers on SE Photography too if you migrate this Question there. Lot of cinematographers etc, frequent that forum.

Answer (score 28):

A rain dripper can also be used, this concentrates the water on whoever/whatever is being filmed and keeps the rest of the crew/equipment dry.  Settings allow for changing the intensity/timing of the rain.

And saves having to wait for exactly the right type of rain to appear when filming.

Something like this.

[image]

Or

[image]

(where you can see a spiralled-up hose with sprinklers sticking out)

Use these and a long-ish lens and your equipment remains toasty dry.